# django pass bound form field value to url as keyword argument results None

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a form to edit an existing set of models. To post the form, I am attempting to direct the action to the url with a keyword argument as the value of the 'id' field in the bound form.  However I receive the following error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /membership/edit/12
Reverse for 'members_edit' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'id': None}' not       found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['membership/edit/(?P<id>\\d{1,5})$']
```

This is the relevant html for my form:

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="{% url 'members_edit' id=edit_member_form.member_id.value %}" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Static ID number -->
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 form-control-static text-big">
        <p><strong>ID #:</strong> &nbsp{{edit_member_form.member_id.value}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

I know the value is not `None` in the form because when I display the bound form before the POST is submitted, the line containing `{{edit_member_form.member_id.value}}` evaluates to an integer (eg, 12) and displays correctly.

I am new to django, but why does `edit_member_form.member_id.value` evaluate to `None` in the `url` tag, but evaluates to the number bound to the form when displaying?

If there is a better technique to get the same desired effect, I'd be more than happy to hear it. Really I just want to post the form back to the same url it has been displayed from, with the keyword intact.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

**Edit:**

```
def members_edit(request, id="1"):
context = { 'active':'members' }
context['filter_list'] = Member.objects.all().order_by('last_name')
id=int(id)
print 'callec'
# if form was submitted
if (request.method == 'POST'):
    edit_member_form = EditMemberForm(request.POST)
    if edit_member_form.is_valid(): #all validation rules pass
        print 'called'
        edit_member_and_pass( edit_member_form.cleaned_data )
        member_id = edit_member_form.cleaned_data['member_id']
        return redirect('members_view', id=member_id)
    else:
        context['edit_member_form'] = edit_member_form
        #return render(request, 'members/members_edit.html', context)
# else display an initial form
else:
    member_set = Member.objects.filter(pk=id)
    # if we find the member
    if ( len(member_set) == 1):
        member = member_set[0]
        member_dict = { k:v for k,v in member.__dict__.items() if k not in ['_state', 'photo']}
        member_dict['member_id'] = id
        # get only their passes for this season, that haven't been flagged lost/stolen
        pass_set = member.pass_set.filter(season=get_current_season(), lost_stolen=False)
        # if the member has one current season pass associated with him
        if ( len(pass_set) == 1):
            member_pass = pass_set[0]
            member_dict['member_type'] = member_pass.member_type
            member_dict['active_id'] = member_pass.active_id
            edit_member_form = EditMemberForm( member_dict)
            context['edit_member_form'] = edit_member_form
            #return render(request, 'members/members_edit.html', context)
        # make sure they don't have too many for some crazy reason
        elif ( len(pass_set) > 1 ):
            context['pass_error'] = True
            context['pass_error_msg'] = 'Error: Member has too many active passes for this season.\nPlease have a director edit this record directly.'
            #return render(request, 'members/members_edit.html', context)
        # else the member hasn't been enrolled yet for this season
        # so we want to reenroll them
        else:
            edit_member_form = EditMemberForm( member_dict )
            context['edit_member_form'] = edit_member_form
            #return render(request, 'members/members_edit.html', context)
    # if for some crazy reason there are multiple members with this id    
    elif ( len(member_set) >1):
        context['member_error'] = True
        context['member_error_msg'] = 'Error: Multiple members with id ' + str(id) +'\nPlease have a director edit these records directly'
        #return render(request, 'members/members_edit.html', context)
    # else the member doesn't exist
    else:
        context['member_error'] = True
        context['member_error_msg'] = "Error: Member doesn't exist.\nPlease sign them up as new"
        #return render(request, 'members/members_edit.html', context)
return render(request, 'members/members_edit.html', context)
```

**EDIT 2:** The issue appears to be that the value of `edit_member_form.member_id` is not staying bound to the form field when submitting. I'm not sure why this would happen though.

If I display the the field itself, the form submits successfully.
Ie,

```
<p><strong>ID #:</strong> &nbsp{{edit_member_form.member_id}}</p>
```

works but

```
<p><strong>ID #:</strong> &nbsp{{edit_member_form.member_id.value}}</p>
```

doesn't.

How can I display a field value, without it being editable, but so that the value remains bound to the form?

**EDIT 3:**
Here is the relevant code from my `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('members.views',
    url(r'^membership/view/(?P<id>\d{1,5})$', 'members_view', name='members_view'),  # view members page
    url(r'^membership/edit/(?P<id>\d{1,5})$', 'members_edit', name='members_edit'),  # edit members page
```

Also, in my own attempts to solve the problem, I believe it can be solved if I can write the markup so that is displays the value but also posts that value on submit.  I think the issue is that the

```
<p><strong>ID #:</strong> &nbsp{{edit_member_form.member_id}}</p>
```

evaluates to an `<input>` field in markup, which gets posted when the form is submitted.  Since just displaying the value does not evaluate to including this input tag, the values are not posted to the request.  So now the question becomes how do I post data to the request on form submit without an `<input>` field? Should I perhaps intervene with something a bit more hacky, like jQuery?

**SOLUTION**
Finally, the solution is to add a hidden input in the field containing the value to submit. It essentially amounted to just this one extra line after displaying the field

```
<p class="form-control-static" id="id_member_id">{{edit_member_form.member_id.value}}</p>
<input type="hidden" id="id_member_id" name="member_id" value="{{edit_member_form.member_id.value}}">
```

Comment: Can you please post your views.py? And did you try `action="{% url 'members_edit' edit_member_form.member_id.value %}"`

Comment: I have posted the view.  It's not entirely finished, but the definition does require a keyword argument `id`, which I believe is the relevant aspect for this issue.  Also I did try that, but then I get the same error only with a positional argument `(None,)` instead of the keyword argument error.

Comment: Isn't member_id same as edit_member_form.member_id.value??

Comment: Yes they represent the same thing.  I tried passing the `member_id` straight into the html through the context by adding `context['member_id'] = member_id`, and this fixed the redirect problem, but now the form isn't valid because `edit_member_form.member_id` and `edit_member_form.active_id` are both `None`.  The underlying issue here is that those values don't appear to be rebound in the form on submit.

Comment: What is your `urls.py`?

Comment: Posted. Although I don't think the urls are the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may be as simple as removing the "action" attribute from your form. If you do this, the form will post back to itself; i.e., a form on /membership/edit/12/ will post to /membership/edit/12/.

This will eliminate any need for your to print the id in any form on the page.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know I could do that.  Unfortunately it seems that if I don't display it as the field, it doesn't get added to the POST request, which leaves it blank and so the form won't validate. I suppose I need to post them myself.